# Why can't I load System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData when it's on the same directory as the executable

Tags: c#, deployment

I'm trying to run a deployed .net application on a clean machine, with .net core and .net framework installed, but I'm getting this error:

[image]

It seems to be looking for `System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData` inside the path `runtimes/win/lib/netstandard2.0/`

I copied the dll file to the directory and it worked. Any idea why it doesn't look for the dll on the same directory as the executable?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clearer, but thank you for the advice JohnB.

Comment: This API is not available "in" .NET Standard 2.0, but it is available "for" .NET Standard 2.0 as a "Platform Extension" which means that there is a NuGet package you have to add to get support for it.  When you publish ensure that this is getting packaged

Comment: Thank you JohnB, that was the reason. We had referenced a project that used the dll but we never installed it through Nuget on the current project.

Weird is that on our other computers, this doesn't happen. Thanks for your help!

Comment: ok, i have added an answer now, if happy click the tick.  cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This API is not available "in" .NET Standard 2.0, but it is available "for" .NET Standard 2.0 as a "Platform Extension" which means that there is a NuGet package you have to add to get support for it. When you publish ensure that this is getting packaged.

Comment: For completeness: the nuget package name is System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData